# How to restrict characters using validation rule in Microsoft Access?

Tags: validation, ms-access, rules, restriction

I need to create a validation rule, that checks if inserted text complies to national identification number standards (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number). 
In the identification number, allowed are following: letters (along with letters outside ASCII a-zA-Z), numbers, spaces, hyphens, plus signs, equal signs and slashes.

Writing individual restriction for every character would mean the validation rule to be extremely long

`...WHERE (National_ID LIKE "0##########") OR (National_ID LIKE "0############")`

and I am wondering if there is better way that would make more sense.
Also, Access does not support Regex, which complicates the task even further.

Comment: Regex can be used in VBA so VBA to validate data is an option.

Comment: speaking of regex, you need to know the pattern first. Which country is in question?